# Mongoose send requested to nested schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't quite understand why my requests are not added to my DB. I have schema with nested objects. So I try to send requst to specific object inside of an object. Result says scucces, however nothing is added.

Here's schema:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    connections: {
        parents: {type : Array},
        children: {type : Array}
    }
})
```

Here's router:

```
router.patch('/v2/:id', getPerson, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.connections != null) {
        if (req.body.connections.parents != null) { res.person.connections.parents.push(req.body.connections.parents); }
        if (req.body.connections.children != null) { res.person.connections.children.push(req.body.connections.children); }
    }
    try {
        const updatePerson = await res.person.save();
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success' })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: error.message })
    }
})
```

Here's middelware:

```
async function getPerson(req, res, next) {
    let person;
    try {
        person = await Person.findById(req.params.id);
        if (person === null) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Cannot find the person' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
    res.person = person;
    next();
}
```

Here's request:

```
PATCH http://localhost:3100/api-db/v2/62e28682cecc9120c7af9de5
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "connections.parents" : "test"
}
```

Connection is established, document in db is alredy created.

It seems to me that I might doing wrong requst. I couldn't find information about nested requsts though.

What seems to be the problem?

P.S.

Other requsts that are not nested are satisfied...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just missed some syntax:

```
{
    "connections" : {"parents" : "test"}
}
```